# Rotating fermion and spin structure on manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, electrons, wavefunction, quantum-spin, spinors

We know that doing a 2$\pi$ rotation would give a minus sign to wavefunctions of electrons. Since electrons are spin $1/2$ objects. How is this related to the spin structure on the manifold in which electrons live?

Or if we have an electron residing on a circle $S^1$, with spin-orbit coupling, we know that rotating the electron a full circle would give its wavefunction a minus sign. We also know that $H^1(S^1,\mathbb{Z}_2)=\mathbb{Z}_2$ meaning we have two spin structure on $S^1$, the periodic one $\psi(x+L)=\psi(x)$ and the antiperiodic one $\psi(x+L)=-\psi(x)$. How are these two things related?